# double free or corruption (out) from psycopg2 connect using python 3.11.6

Tags: psycopg2, postgresql-10, python-3.11, double-free

I have a python application which uses postgres and works fine in a conda envirnment based on python 3.7.3.
I am trying to update its conda environment to use a newer python version.
I built the new environment ground up by repeatedly running the application to find missing packages and the installing them.
Executing this script in the new environment:

import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' host='localhost' password='dbpass'")

Produces:
double free or corruption (out)
Aborted (core dumped)
in the connect.

The postgres version is 10.
I see this in /var/log/postgressql/postgresql-10-main.log evey time it's run:
2023-12-07 10:05:52.855 GMT [6618] [unknown]@[unknown] FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet

> > > psycopg2.**version**
> > > '2.9.9 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)'
> > > python --version
> > > Python 3.11.6

Whether or not the username is correct, it shouldn't cause a core dump.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of psycopg2 is that? May it be that it dropped support for postgresql-10? Because postgres is a few major versions behind.

Comment: 1) `psycopg2` uses `libpq` which is backwards compatible to Postgres 7.4, so it will handle Postgres 10.  2) How did you install `psycopg2`? 3) Did you reinstall/rebuild it when you changed the Cond env?

Comment: That doesn't depend on the username: I'm also getting "FATAL:  no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet" in my PG logs however using a separate installation of python with the appropriate libraries, out of conda, does not show this issue though the exact same code runs with the same credentials.

Comment: Hi.
I'm still not clear what the issue was that caused my problem, but it has resolved.
I did:
conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda
And the situation improved.
Conda then gave me a more useful error message - forget the details sorry - and I was able to resolve problems.
Thanks to Adrian, Julaine and Ten for responding to this.
Ian.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, a workaround for me was downgrading openssl from 3.2.0 to 3.1.4:
`conda install openssl=3.1.4`
https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1658

Don't know why this is happening, maybe someone has more details.

Another workaround: install psycopg2-binary (or psycopg[binary] if you use psycopg version 3). That version has inbuilt ssl and libpq

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue without conda as well, with simply my system openssl library being upgraded to 3.2.0.

An alternative workaround to downgrading openssl is to install **psycopg2-binary** instead of psycopg2.

Someone came up with a patch in postgresql: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CX9SU44GH3P4.17X6ZZUJ5D40N@neon.tech, so you should expect the issue to be resolved fairly soon.